# Ninject Property Injection on base class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm attempting to inject a property using `ninject`. Given the two bindings in the `ninject` module below, I would expect the `ConcreteDependency` to be injected into `B`. 
However, it seems that `WhenInjectedInto` doesn't consider the type being injected into, just the declaring type of the target (property in this case).

Is there a way to achieve the behaviour I expected?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel(new TestModule());
    var b = kernel.Get<B>();
    var c = kernel.Get<C>();
}

class TestModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IDependency>().To<EmptyDependency>();
        Bind<IDependency>().To<ConcreteDependency>().WhenInjectedInto<B>();
    }
}

abstract class A
{
    [Inject]
    public IDependency Dependency { get; set; }
}

class B : A {}

class C : A {}

interface IDependency {}

class EmptyDependency : IDependency { }

class ConcreteDependency : IDependency { }
```

Comment: How you register A, B and C into NInject?

Comment: You don't have to in Ninject. Since `B` and `C` are concrete classes they don't need to be registered explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to check against a concrete type, you can use `ParentContext.Plan.Type` on the `IRequest` interface. This should give you the behaviour you expected from `WhenInjectedInto`. For example:

```
When(req => req.ParentContext.Plan.Type == typeof(B))
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use constructor injection instead of property injection if possible. This is a better technique, which is recommended by Mark Seeman, because makes dependencies required for object construction explicit and object signature via constructor is more expressive. Code should look like this:

```
    abstract class A
    {
        public IDependency Dependency { get; private set; }

        public A (IDependency dependency)
        {
            Dependency = dependency;
        }

    }

    class B : A
    {
        public B (IDependency dependency)
            : base(dependency)
        {

        }
    }

    class C : A
    {
        public C (IDependency dependency)
            : base(dependency)
        {

        }
    }

    interface IDependency { }

    class EmptyDependency : IDependency { }

    class ConcreteDependency : IDependency { }
```

Configuration will be the same as in you example. The following test passes

```
    [Test]
    public void TestSpecificBindingToObjectB()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(new TestModule());
        var b = kernel.Get<B>();
        var c = kernel.Get<C>();

        Assert.AreNotEqual(b.Dependency.GetType(), c.Dependency.GetType());
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(ConcreteDependency), b.Dependency.GetType());
    }
```

If you have an optional dependency with default implementation and you are ok with decorating your classes with `Inject` attribute, you can can pull parent information from request, like this:

```
class TestModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IDependency>().To<EmptyDependency>();
        Bind<IDependency>().To<ConcreteDependency>().When(req =>req.ParentContext.Request.Service == typeof(B));
    }
}
```

Then the same test given above passes for your class hierarchy with property injection.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I'd like to get it to work for property injection. The dependency, in this case, is something which can have a reasonable default value (the Empty Dependency) so I was moving it from constructor injection to property injection to avoid having too many constructor parameters.

Comment: I attempted to use the `When` extension method with a predicate which would use the type being injected into, rather than the property's declaring type but couldn't work out how to get the necessary information from the `IRequest`.

Comment: I have updated my answer with respect to your case of optional dependency with default implementation

Comment: I also had an issue with constructor injection because a generic type can only be instantiated by a parameterless constructor, effectively disallowing required parameters.